# How to Autoincrement the TextView value in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

> I want to Increment the TextView's value in Android Studio automatically but the problem i am facing is > when i run the following code it only show the app interface when the code is finished. Any Solution?

```
package com.example.assignment2;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import static android.os.SystemClock.sleep;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private TextView tv;
int count = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.t);
    while(count<10000000) {
    count++;
    tv.setText("" + count);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Android Studio is only a IDE environment. The significant flaw is with your code where your loop (while) through 10B of records just do a set text for the same text column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int counter = 0;
            while (counter < 10000000) {
                counter++;
                final String counterStr = counter.toString();
                tv.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText(counterStr);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that:

On Android, there is something called **Main Thread**. This thread is responsible for rendering all the UI of your app, if this thread is busy with any other task (like run a while with 10.000.000 of loops) your UI will just freeze because there are no resources available to render the UI. To avoid that kind of issue, you should run the heavy part of your code in a separate thread, and all the UI updates on the main / UI thread (both are the same thing). Making these changes your code will look like that:

```
package com.example.assignment2;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import static android.os.SystemClock.sleep;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private TextView tv;
int count = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.t);
    //Creating a new thread
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //This while will run on this new thread
                while(count<10000000) {
                    count++;
                    /*To ensure that the TextView update will run on the right thread
                    * we should run this update inside the runOnUiThread method*/
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tv.setText("" + count);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
}
```

To learn more about thread take a look at this article:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads